# IOS Application is not working when i updated my Phone IOS with this error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

My application was working completely fine with one cocoapod (CSV.swift). I updated the iOS version of my phone today and after that my app stopped working and showing this error 

later I removed the version of my pods and reinstall it with no version mentioned in the pod file but still not working. Anyone can help?

```
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1464C2C5-D4B1-43F2-9FC1-7D67A35549C7/TrackerConfiguration.app/Frameworks/CSV.framework/CSV: stat() failed with errno=25
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1464C2C5-D4B1-43F2-9FC1-7D67A35549C7/TrackerConfiguration.app/Frameworks/CSV.framework/CSV: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1464C2C5-D4B1-43F2-9FC1-7D67A35549C7/TrackerConfiguration.app/Frameworks/CSV.framework/CSV'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1464C2C5-D4B1-43F2-9FC1-7D67A35549C7/TrackerConfiguration.app/Frameworks/CSV.framework/CSV: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1464C2C5-D4B1-43F2-9FC1-7D67A35549C7/TrackerConfiguration.app/Frameworks/CSV.framework/CSV: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1464C2C5-D4B1-43F2-9FC1-7D67A35549C7/TrackerConfiguration.app/Frameworks/CSV.framework/CSV'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1464C2C5-D4B1-43F2-9FC1-7D67A35549C7/TrackerConfiguration.app/Frameworks/CSV.framework/CSV: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6>

Comment: first line of the error is 
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CSV.framework/CSV

Comment: Did you try removing the library and adding again?

Comment: yes, i did. i removed the pods and restarted xcode , deleted app my phone and reinstalled it later. but still facing the same issue